# How to rewrite an URL on a JBoss server?

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, jboss, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect/rewrite this two kinds of URLs:

- mydomain.com -> newdomain.com
- mydomain.com/specificPage -> newdomain.com/newSpecificPage
- mydomain.com/anyOtherPage -> mydomain.com/anyOtherPage (no redirect here)

So I just want to redirect the root domain to a new domain, and *some* pages from my domain to some pages on a new domain...

How can I do that on a JBoss server ?

Answer (score 11):

Have you looked into http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/modules/rewrite.html? It looks like what you're looking for, and it's pretty similar to Mod_rewrite for Apache.

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to send an [HTTP 301 Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) response.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^URI_TO_REDIRECT
RewriteRule redirect=301 NEW_SITE [L]
```

or similar. The `[L]` is to tell it to redirect immediately instead of continuing to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are routing through apache at all it is possible to use mod_rewrite; you just need to be careful as to where you declare the rewrite rules. Directory configs and .htaccess files won't work; you need it as a global configuration for the entire host. Similar [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/76402/jboss-modrewrite/79075#79075) on serverfault.